# Python: Appoint vector values after each loop but not for each iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

I wanna have that V_old takes on the values of V after a complete loop over j_now. 
However, V_old takes on the Values of V directly after each j_now iteration and therefore I get wrong values because the new V_old value is always part of the new maximum and so on.

```
for i_iter in range(0,5):
    for j_now in range(0, 400):         
        V[j_now] = np.max(matrix_M[:,j_now] + beta * V_old)
    V_old = V
```

Would be great if sb. could help me! Cheers, Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in python are mutable objects.
To elaborate, when you do:

```
V_old = V
```

then you are not assigning a copy of your V dictionary, you are assigning a direct reference to your dictionary.

That means that both `V_old` and `V` start referring to the **same object** in memory. So after that point, if you edit either of them then both of them will reflect the same changes!

What you probably need is to make a copy of the dictionary.

So you would need to do something like:

```
V_old = deepcopy(V)
```

(check out the documentation for the [**copy**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module for the difference between shallow/deep copy to see which works better on your case)

Edit: I assumed the data structure is a dictionary, but the same would apply for a list and any other mutable data structure.

Comment: Hey Geekfish! That was exactly what i need and after i imported the module for copy it worked directly as I wanted it to have!!! Thank you very much, you saved me !!!